# Duplicating CSS rules in less

Tags: css, less

I have something like this in me .less file

```
.form-section {

.special-check {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    .ui-selectmenu-button();
    width: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

which will ofc. generate `.form-section .special-check` and I want to have something like this `.form-section .special-check, .something` but I don't know how to do it in less. ofc i could just copy and pase rules for `.something` but that's not good solution. Do you know how to do it?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to duplicate the rules:

```
.something {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}   

.form-section {
   .special-check:extend(.something){};
}
```

or also

```
.form-section {
   .special-check {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
      overflow: hidden;
   }
}

.something:extend(.form-section .special-check){};
```

The result is the same, it only depends on *who* is extending *who*

---

Compiled output

```
.form-section .special-check,
.something {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Further reference: http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extending-nested-selectors

Comment: yea but you have duplicated rules here. I want to have these rules only once like this .form-section .special-check, .something

Comment: oh right, see my update

Answer (score -1):

alternatively

```
.form-special {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   .ui-selectmenu-button();
   width: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.form-section { .special-check { .form-special; }}
.something { .form-special; }
```